# multiple service on same port with nginx

Tags: nginx

How can I configure nginx to serve the below two URLs correctly:

http://xyz/service1 -> http://xyz:port1/service1_home

http://xyz/service2 -> http://xyz:port2/service2_home

and if user clicks on login here: http://xyz:port1/service1_login then nginx should show the URL for the user like http://xyz/service1/service1_login

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Look at here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

for example:

    `location /service1 {
     proxy_pass http://xyz:port2/service1_home;
    }
    location /service2 {
     proxy_pass http://xyz:port2/service2_home;
    }`

something like that.

Comment: it's nok OK... as it will redirect login to http://xyz/service1_login instead of http://xyz:port1/service1_login ...

Comment: so, this is changing the URL on user side, and I don't want that...
I want that the URI is always starting with the service name (so the correct URL , where the service is listening really is hidden from the user point of view)